# Get one item from many using slug in Ember.js

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

I have these two models:

```
deomens.Artwork = DS.Model.extend({
    title: DS.attr('string'),
    slug: DS.attr('string'),
    description: DS.attr('string'),
    thumbnail: DS.attr('string'),
    artwork: DS.attr('string'),
    created_at: DS.attr('string'),
    updated_at: DS.attr('string'),
    options: DS.hasMany('option', {async: true}),
    hasOptions: Ember.computed.gt('options.length',0)
});

deomens.Option = DS.Model.extend({
    name: DS.attr('string'),
    detail: DS.attr('string'),
    artwork: DS.belongsTo('artwork')
});
```

I'm using the `RESTAdapter` like this:

```
deomens.Store = DS.Store.extend({
    revision: 12,
    adapter: DS.RESTAdapter.create({
        namespace: 'deomens/public/api'
    })
});

deomens.ArtworkSerializer = DS.RESTSerializer.extend(DS.EmbeddedRecordsMixin, {
  attrs: {
    options: { embedded: 'always', serialize: 'ids', deserialize: 'records' }
  }
});
```

Here is my router:

```
deomens.Router.map(function(){
    this.resource('artworks');
    this.resource('artwork', {path: '/view/:slug'});
});
```

And here are the two routes I've created:

```
deomens.ArtworksRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function(){
        return this.store.findAll('Artwork');
    }
});

deomens.ArtworkRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function(params){
        //need to return a single item based on slug
        //something like return this.store.find('Artwork', {slug: params.slug});
    }
});
```

ArtworksRoute works fine - it returns all the artworks with their options.

However whenever I go to `/view/artworkSlug`, it fires up another GET request. So can I not get an item from already retrieved data? That's one question.

The second question - let's say if I make it fire up another GET request using:

```
return this.store.find('Artwork', {slug: params.slug});
```

it sends a GET request to the following URL:

```
/api/artworks?slug=artworkSlug
```

Can't I change this to something like this?

```
/api/view/slug
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind the first question - it was a bad idea as someone landing on a specific artwork page, would not have all the artworks cached to find one.

As for the second question, I had to use return this.store.find('Artwork', params.slug); instead.